# Java code to display the higher version among the two given values

Tags: java

Java code to display the higher version among the two given values.

```
Version1=7.3.4.2.5.9
Version2=7.3.2.3.8.1
```

It should return the value of version 1 as its greater than version 2.

I tried splitting the number based on .(dot) and then comparing one by one. But its seems not a good approach . Any other approach or suggestion?

My Approach

```
class App {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Version1 = "7.3.4.02.5.9";
    String Version2 = "7.3.4.3.8.1";
    String[] v1Split = Version1.split("\\.");
    String[] v2Split = Version2.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i < v1Split.length; i++) {
        if (v2Split != null) {
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(v1Split[i]);
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(v2Split[i]);
            if (v1 > v2) {
                System.out.println(Version1);
                break;
            }
            if (v2 > v1) {
                System.out.println(Version2);
                break;
            }
            if (v1 == v2)
                continue;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: good luck, we're not here to do your homework for you

Comment: Please provide more details. Show what you tried to do and more details about your question.

Comment: You could also compare the version strings lexicographically if you felt like it. That would also work if characters were introduced, or if more than 1 digit appeared between each `.`.

Comment: @Kaushal28 please see my code

Comment: Thanks for making the edit. Downvote converted to upvote, and close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below method will return the bigger version of the two. Hope this helps, let me know any scenario if it doesn't work. Tried few and it worked fine.

```
private static String getGreater(String Version1, String Version2){
        //Splitting numbers to String array based on .
        String[] v1 = Version1.split("\\.");
        String[] v2 = Version2.split("\\.");

        //Start with any one of the splitted array
        for(int i = 0;i < v1.length;i++){
            int a1 = Integer.parseInt(v1[i]);
            int a2 = Integer.parseInt(v2[i]);
            //Start from left to right, Convert to int and then check for which is greater. When you find greater return specified version
            if(a1 > a2){
                return Version1;
            }else if(a1 < a2){
                return Version2;
            }
        }
        //If you reach here either one of the version is null/blank  or both are same so return anythign. You might need to check at your end
        //that you don't send null or blanks to this method/
        return Version1;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a comparator which splits each version string into parts and then compares parts at the same position one by one, returning on first inequality. If parts at all existing positions are equal then version with more parts is bigger:

```
"1.2" < "1.3" < "1.3.1" == "1.3.1" < "1.3.1.1" < "1.4"
```

Here is such comparator:

```
class VersionComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
        List<String> v1 = Arrays.asList(version1.split("\\."));
        List<String> v2 = Arrays.asList(version2.split("\\."));
        return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(v1.size(), v2.size()))
                .map(i -> Integer.valueOf(v1.get(i)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(v2.get(i))))
                .filter(i -> i != 0)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(Integer.compare(v1.size(), v2.size()));
    }
}
```

And example and proof of work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] versions = new String[]{
            "7.3.4.2.5.9",
            "7.3.2.3.8.1",
            "7.2",
            "7.3.0",
            "7.13.0",
            "6.4.2.3.5",
            "7.3.2.3",
            "7.3.4.2.5.9.1",
    };

    Stream.of(versions)
            .sorted(new VersionComparator())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Result:

```
6.4.2.3.5
7.2
7.3.0
7.3.2.3
7.3.2.3.8.1
7.3.4.2.5.9
7.3.4.2.5.9.1
7.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class `Version` that represent version you try to compare and make this class implement interface `Comparable`.

```
   public final class Version implements Comparable<Version> {
    private final String versionString;

    public Version(String versionString) {
        this.versionString = versionString;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Version otherVersion) {
        Iterator<Integer> thisChunks = this.chunksIterator();
        Iterator<Integer> otherChunks = otherVersion.chunksIterator();
        while (thisChunks.hasNext()) {
            if (!otherChunks.hasNext()) break;
            int thisNumber = thisChunks.next();
            int otherNumber = otherChunks.next();
            if (thisNumber != otherNumber) {
                return thisNumber - otherNumber;
            }
        }
        return otherChunks.hasNext() ? -1 : 0;
    }

    private Iterator<Integer> chunksIterator() {
        List<Integer> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(versionString.split("\\."))
                .forEach(chunk -> chunks.add(Integer.parseInt(chunk)));
        return chunks.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return versionString;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Version version = (Version) o;

        return versionString != null ? versionString.equals(version.versionString) : version.versionString == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return versionString != null ? versionString.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

And here the test for this class:

```
public class VersionTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldSortListWithTwoVersions() throws Exception {
        List<Version> versions = Arrays.asList(
                new Version("1.2.34.5"),
                new Version("1.2.5.7")
        );
        List<Version> expectedVersions = Arrays.asList(
                new Version("1.2.5.7"),
                new Version("1.2.34.5")
        );
        versions.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedVersions, versions);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSortListWithManyVersions() throws Exception {
        List<Version> versions = Arrays.asList(
                new Version("7.13.0"),
                new Version("7.3.2.3"),
                new Version("7.3.2.3.8.1"),
                new Version("6.4.2.3.5"),
                new Version("7.2"),
                new Version("7.3.0"),
                new Version("7.3.4.2.5.9"),
                new Version("7.3.4.2.5.9.1")
        );
        List<Version> expectedVersions = Arrays.asList(
                new Version("6.4.2.3.5"),
                new Version("7.2"),
                new Version("7.3.0"),
                new Version("7.3.2.3"),
                new Version("7.3.2.3.8.1"),
                new Version("7.3.4.2.5.9"),
                new Version("7.3.4.2.5.9.1"),
                new Version("7.13.0")
        );
        versions.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedVersions, versions);
    }

}
```

assume `junit` in your classpath

If you think parsing and converting string is dirty way and when you will found better approach you may be replace this seamlessly because this is implementation details of your class `Version`.

Comment: if the version contains double digits like 1.2.34.5 and 1.2.5.7, here replacing the former will return 12345 which is greater than 1257. Seems this will work only for single digit.

Comment: @TulsiJain update solution according to your use case